# How do I transfer input from a jade file to my index.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the call in my Jade file

```
extends layout
block content
h1= title

 input#input(type="text", result="result") <----------Input called

 form(method="post", action="/postquery")
  button(type="submit") Search  
div
form(method="get", action="/")
  button(type="submit") Home
```

Here is the code I tried to use to call it in "index.js"

```
router.post('/postquery', function(input, res) {
  for (i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
      queryResults.push(input);

       if (state[i].name == input){
         queryResults.push(input);
       }        

console.log('This is your input: %s',input);
```

When I print the console log it reads "This is your input: [object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

`%s` is the string formatting syntax that dates back to `sprintf` function in C.

It tells the `console.log` to format your `input` (which is an Object) into string.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object

And the default String value associated with all objects is `"[object`*`type`*`]"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

To parse it as the object that it is, you either need use the [`utils.inspect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options), or just pass the object to `console.log` without the `%s` syntax and it'll automatically use `utils.inspect()` to expand the object.

```
console.log('This is your input:', input);
// => This is your input: {result: 'input'}
```